# (RuntimeError) `module` not set in Guardian pipeline . How to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

[Github link](https://github.com/ankit-kumar-dwivedi/slicker) of my project.

[The Tutorial I am following](https://medium.com/@benhansen/lets-build-a-slack-clone-with-elixir-phoenix-and-react-part-1-project-setup-3252ae780a1)

This is error on my terminal for api(phoenix server)

```html
[error] #PID<0.560.0> running Slicker.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/users
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) `module` not set in Guardian pipeline
        lib/guardian/plug/pipeline.ex:240: Guardian.Plug.Pipeline.raise_error/1
        lib/guardian/plug/verify_header.ex:84: Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader.call/2
        (slicker) web/router.ex:12: Slicker.Router.api/2
        (slicker) web/router.ex:1: Slicker.Router.match_route/4
        (slicker) web/router.ex:1: Slicker.Router.do_call/2
        (slicker) lib/slicker/endpoint.ex:1: Slicker.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (slicker) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Slicker.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (slicker) lib/slicker/endpoint.ex:1: Slicker.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /media/ankit/FE3055EB3055AB81/project/slicker/api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why am i getting this error? I am following the tutorial step by step

Comment: Looks like the server handling your response had an error, not your code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add this to your pipeline:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.Pipeline, module: App.Guardian, error_handler: App.Web.SessionController
```

You should also check that you're using the same version of Guardian that the tutorial is using. They introduced many changes to the 1.0 release of Guardian compared to previous versions of the library.